# How to find the ratio in a pandas series for a groupby function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have used `groupby` to group the dataset by the occupations and gender. Now I want to find the ratio between male and females for each occupation. I am unable to think of how to proceed.

[image]

Comment: Post this data frame as text rather than image

Comment: gender
occupation gender 
administrator F 36
M 43
artist F 13
M 15
doctor M 7
educator F 26
M 69
engineer F 2
M 65
entertainment F 2
M 16
executive F 3
M 29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x=users.groupby(['occupation','gender'])['gender'].count()
    y=users.groupby(['occupation'])['gender'].count()
    r=((x/y)*100).round(2)
    print(r)

#ratio rule "x" is a count of gender(male/female), "y" is the total count of gender

occupation     gender
administrator  F          45.57
               M          54.43
artist         F          46.43
               M          53.57
doctor         M         100.00
educator       F          27.37
               M          72.63
engineer       F           2.99
               M          97.01
entertainment  F          11.11
               M          88.89
executive      F           9.38
               M          90.62
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way using [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) and vectorised Pandas calculations. Note this method removes the need to perform a separate `groupby`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'F'], ['A', 'F'], ['A', 'M'], ['B', 'M'], ['B', 'M'], ['B', 'F'],
                   ['C', 'M'], ['C', 'M'], ['D', 'F']], columns=['Occupation', 'Gender'])

# pivot input dataframe
res = df.pivot_table(index='Occupation', columns='Gender', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)

# calculate ratios
sums = res[['F', 'M']].sum(axis=1)
res['FemaleRatio'] = res['F'] / sums
res['MaleRatio'] = res['M'] / sums

print(res)

Gender      F  M  FemaleRatio  MaleRatio
Occupation                              
A           2  1     0.666667   0.333333
B           1  2     0.333333   0.666667
C           0  2     0.000000   1.000000
D           1  0     1.000000   0.000000
```

Comment: Is it possible to select only the male values from this series?

Comment: @Akshit, Not sure what you mean. Feel free to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51010770/edit) with a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Maybe quite late to the party but here's what I believe is the exact answer:

```
# create pivot
male_ratio = users.pivot_table(index='occupation', columns='gender', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)

# calculate male ratio
sums = male_ratio[['F', 'M']].sum(axis=1)
male_ratio['MaleRatio'] = round(100 * male_ratio['M'] / sums , 1)

# result
male_ratio['MaleRatio']

occupation
administrator     54.4
artist            53.6
doctor           100.0
educator          72.6
engineer          97.0
entertainment     88.9
executive         90.6
healthcare        31.2
homemaker         14.3
lawyer            83.3
librarian         43.1
marketing         61.5
none              55.6
other             65.7
programmer        90.9
retired           92.9
salesman          75.0
scientist         90.3
student           69.4
technician        96.3
writer            57.8
Name: MaleRatio, dtype: float64
```